# swift post gif animation to twitter

Tags: xcode, swift, animation, twitter, uiimage

using swift language, I'm trying to post a created gif animation to twitter, however the interface only supports addImage - posting ordinary images. When I'm saving gif to photos, using

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
            var library : ALAssetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()

            library.writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum(data, metadata: nil, completionBlock:{
                (assetURL: NSURL!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            })
```

it works fine, and one can post gif animation from the photos , however, there is no such thing in twitter interface to post it from the app .

there were some suggestions like creating animatedimagewithimages:

```
 let im = UIImage.animatedImageWithImages(imga, duration: 0.1)
                tweetSheet.addImage(im)
```

but id doesn't work either, posting a static image.

Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter supports animated Gifs now, so not sure if you have resolved your issue.  I've tested this code with animated Gifs.

```
func tweetWithImage(data:NSData)
{

    let account = ACAccountStore()
    let accountType = account.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(
        ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)

    account.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(accountType, options: nil,
        completion: {(success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if success {
                let arrayOfAccounts =
                account.accountsWithAccountType(accountType)

                if arrayOfAccounts.count > 0 {
                    let twitterAccount = arrayOfAccounts.first as! ACAccount
                    var message = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
                    message["status"] = "Test Tweet with image"

                    let requestURL = NSURL(string:
                        "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")
                    let postRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType:
                        SLServiceTypeTwitter,
                        requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.POST,
                        URL: requestURL,
                        parameters: message)

                    postRequest.account = twitterAccount
                    postRequest.addMultipartData(data, withName: "media", type: nil, filename: nil)

                    postRequest.performRequestWithHandler({
                        (responseData: NSData!,
                        urlResponse: NSHTTPURLResponse!,
                        error: NSError!) -> Void in
                        if let err = error {
                            println("Error : \(err.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                        println("Twitter HTTP response \(urlResponse.statusCode)")

                    })
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // do what you want here

            }
    })
}
```

I've put a tutorial on my blog with the corresponding project in GitHub that illustrates using SLRequest so that animated GIFs are supported...you can see it here: http://www.iosinsight.com/twitter-integration-with-swift/

Note: Blog code and the snippet in this answer updated from using "update_with_media" to simply "update" for the request URL, since latter is deprecated in the Twitter API.